# Different MDX query results in SSAS 2005, 2012 and 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssas

For a customer I have 1 same cube definition on 3 different SSAS instances.
The first is SQL Server 2005 (9.00.4060.00), the second 2012 (11.0.3412.0) and the third 2014 (12.0.2430.0).

The cube contains a parent-child dimension used for account intelligence.
The customer connects to the cube using Excel, resulting in this MDX query:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY
Hierarchize(AddCalculatedMembers({DrilldownLevel({[Organisatie Kpl].[Organisatie structuur].[All]})})) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,
[Organisatie Kpl].[Organisatie structuur].[Bestuur].[Lvl3] ON COLUMNS  
FROM (SELECT ({[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763955],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763967],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763969],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763970],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763972],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763973],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763974],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763976],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763977],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763978],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763979],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763980],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763981],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763982],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763983],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763984],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763985],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763986],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763987],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763988],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763989],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763990],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763991],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763992],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763994],[Grootboek].[Grootboek schema].&[763996]}) ON COLUMNS  FROM [Financien]) WHERE ([Financiele Periode].[Financiele Periodes].[Jaar].&[2015],[Measures].[Realisatie]) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS
```

The sub-query contains members of the parent-child-dimension of two different levels, in this case levels 4 and 5.

When I run this query on SQL Server 2005 it gives me the expected result.

On SQL Server 2012 I get an error:

> "Expression cannot be resolved in the context of an arbitrary shape"

And SQL Server 2014 gives a faulty result.

Why do the different SSAS engines act differently and, more importantly, how can I resolve this on the 2014 instance?

Comment: Do you have the latest Cumulative Updates installed for 2012 & 2014?   We found a bug in 2012 SSAS as recently as 6 months ago that was just patched in a January 2015 CU.

Comment: Hi, We will install the CU's and test it again.
My main problem is not SSAS 2012 but SSAS 2014.

Comment: All the more reason why it could be a bug in the product.   If you install the latest CU and the problem persists, I'd open a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: Installed latest CU for SSAS 2014.
Problem persists